# Error building Gradle in new Project after including Appcombat V7

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       E:\Programme\AndroidStudio\sdk\build-tools\21.0.0\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I E:\Programme\AndroidStudio\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar -M C:\Users\nick\AndroidStudioProjects\MaterialBasicApp\app\build\intermediates\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\nick\AndroidStudioProjects\MaterialBasicApp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Users\nick\AndroidStudioProjects\MaterialBasicApp\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\nick\AndroidStudioProjects\MaterialBasicApp\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\nick\AndroidStudioProjects\MaterialBasicApp\app\build\intermediates\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package eu.twenty1media.materialbasicapp -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\nick\AndroidStudioProjects\MaterialBasicApp\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
>   Error Code:
>       -1073741819

Anyone has a solution for this? Want to add this for Material Design in my App.

Comment: I think you need newer build tools, use `compileSdkVersion 21` with  `buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"` and `targetSdkVersion 21`

Comment: Thanks! buildToolsVersion "21.1.1" was the Problem. Mine was at 21.

Comment: I'm glad that worked! I posted it as an answer, maybe someone else will run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need newer build tools, use `compileSdkVersion 21` with `buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"` and `targetSdkVersion 21`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourcompany.yourpackagename"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
```